# using finitely generated in proof.

Tags: modules, finitely-generated

I am trying to show that:Let $R$ be commutative with unity. if $N$ be a finitely generated $R-$module, then the following conditions are equivalent:

(a) $N$ is a sum of simple modules.

(b) $N$ is a direct sum of simple modules.

(c) Given any submodule $M \subset N,$ there exists a unique submodule $M' \subset N$ such that $N = M \oplus M'. $

---

For $(a) \implies (b),$ I said the following:

Assume $N$ is a sum of simple modules, we want to show that $N$ is a direct sum of simple modules i.e. $N = \oplus_{i=1}^n N_i$ where $N_i$ are simple modules. So to prove this, it is enough to show that $N_i \cap N_j = \phi.$ Assume towards contradiction that $M$ is a submodule of $N_i \cap N_j,$ then $M$ is a submodule of both $N_i, N_j$ but this is not possible because $N_i, N_j$ are simple which means they have no nontrivial submodule.

For $(b) \implies (c),$ I said the following:

Suppose that $N = \oplus_{i=1}^n N_i$ where $N_i$ are simple modules and suppose that $M$ is a submodule $N,$

$(1)$ if $M$ is simple then $M$ will be one of those $N_i.$ Let $M = N_1$ but then I do not know how to complete. Any help will be appreciated in that case.

$(2)$ if $M$ is not simple, also I do not know how to handle that case and I will be beyond grateful for any help.

It is clear to me that I have not used the main assumption that $N$ is a finitely generated $R-$module but I do not know how to use it.

For $(c) \implies (a),$ I said the following:

Given any submodule $M \subset N,$ there exists a unique submodule $M' \subset N$ such that $N = M \oplus M'$ and so $N$ is clearly a sum of modules but how to show that they are simple?

Also, any help will be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your hypotheses lack some necessary precision. Is $R$ commutative? unital? Noetherian, left or right? Is $N$ a left $R$-module? I think you intended $R$ to be commutative but what I wrote below doesn't require it.

$a) \Rightarrow b)$ seems incorrect or at least incomplete. It is possible for a vector space to be a sum of three vector subspaces which aren't in direct sum, even though they are pairwise in direct sum. For instance, $K^2=K(0,1) + K(1,0) + K(1,1)$, and the lines have pairwise intersection zero, but the overall sum isn't direct.

I'd prove it this way: let $N=\sum_i{N_i}$ where $N_i$ is simple. Because $N$ is finitely generated, we can assume that the $N_i$ are finitely many, and we can thus name them $N_1,\ldots,N_m$. For each $i$, call $N_i$ *new* if its intersection with $\sum_{j < i}{N_j}$ is zero. As $N_i$ is simple, if $N_i$ is not new then $N_i \subset \sum_{j < i}{N_j}$. It is then easy enough to check that $N$ is the direct sum of the new $N_i$.

Uniqueness in $b) \Rightarrow c)$ seems false. For instance, in $K^2$, we have $K^2=K(0,1)\oplus K(1,0)=K(0,1)\oplus K(1,1)$. But let's see if we can show existence: write a finite sum $N=\bigoplus_{i \in I}{N_i}$ where the $N_i$ are simple. Let $M$ be a submodule of $N$.

Let $J \subset I$ be a maximal subset such that $\sum_{j \in J}{N_j}$ is in direct sum with $M$. Let's show that $N=M \oplus \sum_{j \in J}{N_j}$. Clearly, it's enough to show that $P = M \oplus \sum_{j \in J}{N_j}$ contains every $N_i$. If $i \in J$, that's clear. If not, we know that $P$ isn't in direct sum with $N_i$ (by maximality of $J$), that is, $P \cap N_i$ is nonzero. As $N_i$ is simple, it follows $N_i \subset P$.

Again, how about existence in $c)$ implying $a)$?
I'll simply prove that every submodule of $N$ satisfies existence in $c)$ as well. Indeed, let $M_1 \subset M$ be submodules, let $M' \subset N$ be such that $M \oplus M'=N$. Let then $M''$ be such that $M' \oplus (M'+M_1)=N$. Let $\pi:N \rightarrow M$ be the projection with kernel $M'$. It's easy to check that $M = \pi(M'') \oplus M_1$.

Note also that every submodule of $N$ is the image of $N$ under some projection so is finitely generated. In particular, every sequence of submodules $(M_n)_n$ such that $M_n \subset M_{n+1}$ is stationary.

Let $(M_n)$ be a sequence of submodules such that $M_n \supset M_{n+1}$. Let $M_n=N_n \oplus M_{n+1}$. Then $\left(\bigoplus_{p \leq n}{N_p}\right)_n$ is a nondecreasing sequence of submodules of $N$ so is stationary, which implies that for $n$ large enough $N_n=0$, ie $M_n=M_{n+1}$ so $M_n$ is stationary.

From this, it follows that the set of nonzero submodules of $N$ has minimal elements (the simple submodules). Let $S$ be their sum, we can write $N=S \oplus S_1$ for some submodule $S_1$. Assume $S_1$ is nonzero: since every non-increasing/nondecreasing sequence of submodules of $S_1$ is stationary, $S_1$ contains a simple submodule $P$. But $P \subset S$ by definition of $S$, so $P \subset S\cap S_1 = \{0\}$, a contradiction. So $N=S$ is sum of simple modules.

Comment: $R$ is commutative with unity ..... I will edit my post .... sorry about that.

Comment: Do you mean in the last line of the proof of $a \implies b$ by saying  "it is easy enough" by the same argument I used in my proof of it?

Comment: No. As I explained, your argument is flawed. The concept of “new submodule” is my way to repair it. For that proof: the $N_i$ that are new are constructed to be in a direct sum. Moreover, you can prove by induction that the $N_j$, $j \leq i$ that are new generate the submodule $\sum_{j \leq i}{N_j}$.

Comment: to be precise ....I meant by the contradiction to being simple modules if there is anything in the intersection? .... I did not mean my full argument.

Comment: Ah, then yes, I am indeed using that (but a non-symmetric version).

Comment: What do you mean by non-symmetric version?

Comment: I am still reading your argument thoroughly ..... I will accept it ... but when I have questions I will ask you (if you do not mind).

Comment: Please do not hesitate if you have any questions. :)

Comment: Can this argument work for $(a) \implies (b)$ ?Assume that $M$ is a sum of simple modules and we want to show that $M$  i.e., $M = \oplus_{i=1}^n M_i$ where $M_i$ are simple modules.To prove this, it is enough to show that $M_i \cap (M_1 \dots M_{i-1} M_{i+1} \dots M_n) = \{0\}.$ Assume towards contradiction that $N$ is a submodule of $M_i \cap (M_1 \dots M_{i-1} M_{i+1} \dots M_n)$ then $N$ is a submodule of all  $M_i, M_1, \dots , M_{i-1} M_{i+1}, \dots, M_n)$  but this is not possible because $M_i, M_1, \dots , M_{i-1} M_{i+1}, \dots, M_n)$ are simple i.e. they have no nontrivial submodule.

Comment: But $M_1\ldots M_{i-1}M_{i+1} \ldots M_n$ (I assume that you mean their sum?) isn’t simple! However, we can say that its intersection with $M_i$ is either zero or $M_i$ – and if it is $M_i$, then we can remove $M_i$. My “new” thing is just a formal way to make this work.

Comment: Yeah I meant their sum .... sorry it is a typo

Comment: But is not the idea of being in the intersection is not possible at all because I have simple modules ...... I mean the intersection must be 0.

Comment: I do not understand the rest of your argument in $a \implies b,$ specifically this statement "It is then easy enough to check that $N$ is the direct sum of the new $N_i$. " could you explain it please?

Comment: Also, in $a \implies b,$ when you conclude that "As $N_i$ is simple, if $N_i$ is not new then $N_i \subset \sum_{j < i}{N_j}$" does not that inclusion leads to a contradiction as all the modules in the sum are simple?

Comment: Sorry if that a stupid question, what is the space $K^2$?

Comment: “It is easy enough” > see my first comment. $K^2$ is the standard vector space of dimension two over a field $K$ – I chose it as an illustration of why a sum of simple modules isn’t simple and and it can contain simple submodules that aren’t factors of the sum.

Comment: Can we proceed by exact sequences for $b \implies c$

Comment: I don’t know, maybe? What did you have in mind?

Comment: In your proof for $(c) \implies (a)$ are you proving that $N$ is a sum of  **finitely many**  simple modules and not only the sum of simple modules ? .... I felt this from this statement of you in your proof "Note also that every submodule of $N$ is the image of $N$ under some projection so is finitely generated. In particular, every sequence of submodules $(M_n)_n$ such that $M_n \subset M_{n+1}$ is stationary. 
"

Comment: If you are not doing what I said in my previous comment, how can I adjust your proof of this part to show that $N$ is a sum of **finitely many** simple modules and not only the sum of simple modules? ..... here is my question about that (in case you want to give a separate answer)  https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4096395/how-to-prove-finitely-many-which-route-is-easier

Comment: In $c \rightarrow a)$, I indeed am proving that $N$ is sum of its simple submodules (of which there can be a lot). But in a finite generating family of $N$, each generator is in the sum of finitely many simple submodules, and thus the generating family is contained in the sum of finitely many simple submodules, and thus the sum of these (finitely many) simple submodules is $N$.

Comment: I think what is unclear for me is, why  "each generator is in the sum of **finitely many** simple submodules"? could you clarify this please?

Comment: Write $N=\sum_{i\in I}{N_i}$ where the $N_i$ are simple, and let $g_j,j \in J$ be a finite generating set for $N$. For each $j$, we can write $g_j=\sum_i{e_{ij}}$, $e_{ij} \in N_i$ and zero for all but finitely many $j$. Let $I_j=\{i \in I,\, e_{ij} \neq 0\}$. Then $g_j \in \sum_{i \in I_j}{N_i}$. Let $I^0=\cup_{j \in J}{I_j}$: then $I^0$ is finite and every $g_j$ is in $\sum_{i \in I^0}{N_i}$, so $N=\sum_{i \in I^0}{N_i}$. Is this clearer now?

Comment: I understood that your $I$ is an indexing set, but is $N = \oplus_j  I_j$, where $I_j$ are simple? explicity what are $I_j$?

Comment: $I_j$ is an index set too. I wrote it in my previous comment – $I_j$ is the set of indices $i$ so that “the” $N_i$-component (not well-defined, of course, but it’s enough to consider one decomposition) of $g_j$ is nonzero.

Comment: So can you explain what is $I^0$ in words please?

Comment: Also,I do not understand the statement "and zero for all but finitely many $j$" in your description for $g_j$, why is that correct?

Comment: I think $g_j$ should be $0$ for all but finitely many $i$ not $j$, do you agree? .....  because I think your indexing set $J$ is assumed already to be finite (if I understand correctly).

Comment: Oops, indeed, $e_{ij}$ is zero for all but finitely many $i$, indeed. Thank you.

Comment: But how did you used the simplicity of the $N_i's$ in this proof that includes $g_j$?

Comment: I didn’t. It’s not necessary for this part that the $N_i$ are simple. But since they started off being simple, at the end I get that $N$ is generated by finitely many simple submodules.

Comment: But in your argument of $g_j$ (I am speaking about your whole comment) where can we add since $N_i's$ are simple then $N$ is generated by finitely many simple submodules?

Comment: ohh, I think your are saying that the proof of **finitely many** (without simple) is related only to that $N$ is finitely generated and there is no need for using that $N_i$ is simple in that proof ..... Is my understanding correct?

Comment: Yes. Basically, what I show is as follows: if $N$ is finitely generated and is the sum of submodules $N_i$, $i \in I$, then $N$ is the sum of finitely many $N_i$.