# how to prove finitely many? which route is easier?

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules, homological-algebra, finitely-generated, semi-simple-rings

I want to prove that: If $N$ is finitely generated semi-simple $R-$module, then $N$ is a sum of **finitely many** simple submodules.

I know that if $N$ is a finitely generated $R-$module, then that the following three conditions are equivalent(I have seen its proof before).

1. $N$ is a sum of simple modules.
2. $N$ is a direct sum of simple modules.
3. Given any submodule $M \subset N,$ there exists a unique submodule $M' \subset N$ such that $N = M \oplus M'.$

And any module satisfying these conditions is called a semi-simple module.

Then, to prove my first statement above, I know that I can adjust my proofs either for $2 \implies 1$ in the statement above or for $3 \implies 1.$ I prefer to prove my first statement to prove that: $N$ is a direct sum of simple modules implies $N$ is a sum of **finitely many** simple modules.

Here is my trial:

Assume that $N$ is a direct sum of simple modules, then, by definition of direct sum, $N$ is a sum of simple modules. But then how can I prove that it is a **finite sum**? could anyone help me in proving this please?

**EDIT:**
Maybe proving that every sequence of submodules of $N$ is stationary is a better way of proving my first statement but in that case I also do not see the proof of **finitely many**.

Any help is appreciated!

**EDIT:**

Since $N$ is semi-simple by assumption, then $N$ is a direct sum of (possibly infinitely many) simple modules. This infinitely many sum can come from either one of those two cases:

$(1)$ $N$ is infinitely generated i.e. generated by an infinite set. But this case is excluded because by assumption our $N$ is finitely generated.

$(2)$ at least one of the generators of $N$ is infinitely generated, which is not our case because each of the generators is simple i.e., it has only two submodules.

Is that reasoning correct or there is a more succinct proof?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A direct sum of infinitely many nonzero (right) modules is not finitely generated.

Indeed, if you're given a family of nonzero module $M_\lambda$, for $\lambda\in\Lambda$, and $x_1,\dots,x_n$ are elements of the direct sum thereof, there exists a finite set $F\subseteq\Lambda$ such that
$$
x_1R+x_2R+\dots+x_nR\subseteq \bigoplus_{\lambda\in F}M_\lambda
$$
and this finite direct sum is a proper submodule of the whole direct sum.

Comment: Sorry I did not get your idea of the proof I am seeking. Or are you correcting a wrong idea I stated in my question?

Comment: @MathFear You know that your module is a direct sum of simple modules; since it is finitely generated by assumption, the number of those simple modules has to be finite, as my argument shows.

Comment: but maybe one of them is infinitely generated? but this is not the case as each of them are simple ..... is that correct?

Comment: @MathFear Where's the problem? No matter what modules you take the direct sum of, if there are infinitely many of them the direct sum isn't finitely generated. Therefore, *If* a direct sum is finitely generated, it has only finitely many (nonzero) summands. And each of them has to be finitely generated, of course, but simple modules are.